# Combining for with repeat loop in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform a 5 fold cross validation on LDA and Neural Net predictions for my data set 'heart' where 't' is my dependent variable. I've first coded for LDA and that is working fine, but when it comes to setting up the 5 times repeat for neural net, I keep getting an 'unexpected repeat' error.

```
buf=NULL
for(repeat in 1:5)
{        
    model=brnn(t~.,heart[-testing,],neurons=2)
    y.net[testing]=predict(model,newdata=inp[testing,])
    buf=rbind(buf,pred)
}
Error: unexpected 'repeat' in "for(repeat"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`repeat` is a key word. It is evaluated and gives the error. Please replace repeat by an other variable name like `repetition`.